# how to map network drive

Tags: shared-folders

i need to if it's possible to map a network drive through Ubuntu and make it remain in MY COMP even if restarted or logged off "as in windows we map network drive through the following options (profile home folder in active directory, or by running script net use) "

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define any drive to be any mount point you like.

There are many ways to do make drive mapping permanent; most are pretty confusing.  However the instructions here are not to bad:
http://refugeeks.com/how-to-automatically-mount-a-network-share-in-ubuntu/